# Call functions from bashrc in inputrc

Tags: bashrc, inputrc

I'm on Arch Linux (4.13.11) and in my `.bashrc`, there's a custom function that finds a file using [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) and then opens that file with the default editor:

```
# Search a file with fzf inside a Tmux pane and then open the file in an editor
fzf_then_open_in_editor() {
  local file=$(fzf-tmux)
  # Open the file if it exists
  if [ -n "$file" ]; then
    # Use the default editor if it's defined, otherwise Vim
    ${EDITOR:-vim} "$file"
  fi
}
```

I've configured my `.inputrc`, to use Vim-like keybindings for the shell:

```
set editing-mode vi
```

Preferably, I could press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> when in command mode to call my function `fzf_then_open_in_editor`.

I tried

```
set keymap vi-command
"\C-o": fzf_then_open_in_editor
```

but that didn't work.

In `.inputrc`, how can I create keybindings for functions defined in `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 3):

The form `key: function` only accepts readline built-in functions. As you found out, to enter text you need what it called a macro which has to be in quotes: `key: "my macro\r"`. I don't see why you need to start with an insert command, as usually you are already in insert mode at the command prompt.

If you want to call a function, use a shell command binding with option `-x`. I don't know of any way to put this binding in a `~/.inputrc`, but you can put the following command in your `.bashrc`:

```
bind -x '"\C-o": fzf_then_open_in_editor'
```

Answer (score 1):

I got what I wanted by adding this to `.inputrc`:

```
set keymap vi-command
# Go to insert mode with i, write the function's name, then hit enter
"\C-o": "ifzf_then_open_in_editor\015"
```

Where `\015` is the keycode for <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This works, but I'm curious if there are more elegant solutions.